# What query would I use to obtain sibling records when using closure tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, transitive-closure-table

If I have the following schema & data and am employing the closure table pattern:

`+----+----------+------------+--------+
| id | ancestor | descendant | length |
+----+----------+------------+--------+
|  1 |        2 |          2 |      0 |
|  2 |        2 |         12 |      1 |
|  3 |        2 |         13 |      1 |
|  4 |        2 |         14 |      1 |
|  5 |        2 |         15 |      1 |
| 10 |       12 |         12 |      0 |
| 11 |       13 |         13 |      0 |
| 12 |       14 |         14 |      0 |
| 13 |       15 |         15 |      0 |
|  9 |       17 |         20 |      1 |
|  8 |       17 |         19 |      1 |
|  7 |       17 |         18 |      1 |
|  6 |       17 |         17 |      0 |
| 14 |       18 |         18 |      0 |
| 15 |       19 |         19 |      0 |
| 16 |       20 |         20 |      0 |
+----+----------+------------+--------+`

What would my join query back to my main table look like to obtain all the sibling rows of row id `2`?

`+----+----------+------------+--------+
| id | ancestor | descendant | length |
+----+----------+------------+--------+
|  3 |        2 |         13 |      1 |
|  4 |        2 |         14 |      1 |
|  5 |        2 |         15 |      1 |
+----+----------+------------+--------+`

Answer (score 2):

The siblings of a given node would have the same ancestor.  However, this would include "1" as well as your list:

```
select t.*
from table t 
where t.ancestor = (select ancestor from table t2 where t.id = 2);
```

In your table, I am not sure what it means for `ancestor` to be the same as `descendant`.  But, I think the following is the query you want:

```
select t.*
from table t 
where t.ancestor = (select ancestor from table t2 where t2.id = 2) and
      t.ancestor <> t.descendant and
      t.id <> 2;
```

EDIT:

You can do this as an *explicit* join like this:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     table t2
     on t.ancestor = t2.ancestor and
        t2.id = 2 a
where t.id <> 2 and
      t.ancestor <> t.descendant;
```

Note:  I also added the condition `t.id <> 2` so "2" is not considered a sibling of itself.

Comment: I should have clarified a bit more, but is there a way to do this using a join?  I'm making use of an ORM and would like to model all the connections as relations.

Comment: One issue I realized is that I don't readily know that the ancestor is "2".  I need to join from my main data table, to this one to obtain all the siblings, only knowing the one row of this closure table.

Comment: @Omega . . . "2" isn't the ancestor.  It is the `id` of the row you want the siblings of.

Comment: Yeah, I won't be using that ID when I reference the table. I'll be coming in using either ancestor or descendant (most likely descendant), which are IDs pointing back to the table being related to here.

Comment: Summarized:  I only know an id from the row of the closured table I'm coming from.  I want the descendant value for every sibling entry in the closure table so that I can join back to the closured model itself.